# Linux device driver - memory mapped I/O example discussion

Tags: linux, memory, io, linux-device-driver

I have gone through the following topic and I still have some questions.

[ioread32 followed by iowrite32 not giving same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831583/ioread32-followed-by-iowrite32-not-giving-same-value)

1. In the link, where can I get my `base` which is defined as `0xfed00000`
   in the post ?
2. what should I put for the second parameter in

   `void request_mem_region(unsigned long start, unsigned long len,char *name);`
3. what should I put for the second parameter in

   `void *ioremap_nocache(unsigned long phys_addr, unsigned long size);`
4. By having the Makefile and generating the kernel module, I should use the `insmod` and then `dmesg` to check if the code works as I expect, is this correct ?
5. In the case, should I add `iounmap(virtual_base);` before `return 0;` in the source ?

Thanks

Comment: (1) It's the base (physical) address of the peripheral.  If it's a discrete chip on the board, then consult the board documentation.  If it's an embedded peripheral in a SoC, then consult the memory map in the SoC datasheet. (2) & (3) The length/size is the number of bytes the peripheral's register set occupies.  Sometimes the entire memory region to the next peripheral is specified.  (5) Which return statement?  If **ioremap()** is performed in a driver's probe routine, then the **iounmap()** should be in the probe's error exit *and* in the driver's remove routine.

Comment: @sawdust thanks,can you post it as the answer so that I can check it ?

Comment: @ the item (4) , I think the only way to do it is through dmesg, is there any other easier approach to check the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. In the link, where can I get my base which is defined as 0xfed00000 in the post ?

It's the base (physical) address of the peripheral's registers.
If the peripheral is a discrete chip on the board, then consult the board documentation.
If the peripheral is embedded in a SoC, then consult the memory map in the SoC datasheet.

> 2. what should I put for the second parameter in

```
void request_mem_region(unsigned long start, unsigned long len,char *name);
```

> 3. what should I put for the second parameter in

```
void *ioremap_nocache(unsigned long phys_addr, unsigned long size);
```

These two routines should be called with the same first and second parameters.
The length/size is the number of bytes the peripheral's register set occupies.
Sometimes the entire memory region to the next peripheral is specified.

> 4. By having the Makefile and generating the kernel module, I should use the insmod and then dmesg to check if the code works as I expect, is this correct ?

A judicious sprinkling of **printk()** statements is the tried & true method of testing a Linux kernel driver/module.
Unix has **kdb**.

> 5. In the case, should I add iounmap(virtual_base); before return 0; in the source ?

Do not copy that poorly written example of init code.
If **ioremap()** is performed in a driver's **probe()** (or other initialization) routine, then the **iounmap()** should be in the probe's error exit sequence *and* in the driver's **remove()** (or the complementary to init) routine.
There are numerous examples to study in the Linux kernel source.  Use an online Linux cross reference such as [http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=iounmap)
Note that almost all Linux drivers use **iounmap()** two or more times.