# An example of using request_region and release_region

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ioports

I read about I/O ports and communicating with the hardware, I want to gain access to an I/O port to see a live example of the various functions. I don't understand what the first argument (`unsigned long start`) of `request_region` is.

**I'd like someone to show me a very simple use of these functions.**

```c
struct resource *request_region(unsigned long start, unsigned long n, const char *name);
void release_region(unsigned long first, unsigned long n);
```

**Also, where can we see a list of I/O ports? I guess it might be in `/proc/ioports`?**

Comment: Are you aware of bootlin.com ? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/request_region

Comment: @KamilCuk I am yes, but it just code without any explanation.

Comment: **request_region()** is the modern (combined) version of the  **request_mem_region()** and **ioremap()** calls.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391418/linux-device-driver-memory-mapped-i-o-example-discussion and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580469/content-of-proc-iomem  *"...but it just code without any explanation."* -- Code is the documentation.